# How pass value from input by Session method in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm try to pass a value from my Input to build a filter, I need to get all that values, pass to my controller and manipulate, I puted the input's and created all the things about Controller, but for some reason, my session don't get a value what I specified in the fields. I puted only one example, because the code is long and repeat the logic in all fields.

For example:

I need to get the 'codigopedido' value, so I puted the Input with that attributes:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigopedido" id="codigopedido" placeholder="" value="{{ session('codigopedido') }}">
```

I created a function in my controller to manipulate that value

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $order = Order::query();
        if ($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
          $codigopedido;
          $codigopedido = $data->codigopedido;
          session(['codigopedido' => $codigopedido]);

       if (strlen(session('codigopedido')) > 0)
        {
           $order = $order->where('erp_site', session('codigopedido'));
        }
        $content = $order->paginate(20);

        if ($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            return view('admin.order-table')->with('order', $content);

        } else
        {
            return view('admin.order')->with('order', $content);
        }

    }
```

In my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('blur', '#codigopedido', function() {
        var codigopedido = $('#codigopedido').val();
        searchRequest['codigopedido'] = codigopedido;
        doSearch();
    });
});

function doSearch() {
    $.post(postSearch, {
            'search_database': JSON.stringify(searchRequest),
            '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
        }
        , function(data) {
            $('#order-table').html(data);
        });
}
```

In my view:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/OrderSearch.js') }}"></script>
  <script>
      var postSearch = '{{ route('order::searchPost') }}';
      var searchRequest = {
          'codigopedido': '{{ session('codigopedido') }}',
      };
  </script>
```

I checked what values my session get, and thats is result:

```
a:11:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"TngqBg13IFapNDmM8jGfTpLU0F1IDvsfeqEJmg01";s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"new";a:0:{}s:3:"old";a:0:{}}s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:35:"http://localhost:8000/admin/product";}s:18:"cartalyst_sentinel";s:32:"SE3m6CuxzCRFQafdZM6BwZ2oiShiFcsV";s:9:"descricao";s:0:"";s:5:"model";s:0:"";s:6:"status";s:0:"";s:11:"distributor";s:0:"";s:5:"stock";s:0:"";s:9:"categoria";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:1:"0";}
```

For some reason, the session get only values from another filter, any suggestion?

Comment: What version of laravel. Newer versions limit use of the session class I believe.

Comment: If I use the same fields to save values from different filter, could you run into a problem?

Comment: I believe that is not it, I tested with the fields that I had already used, the problem is in passing the values from the Input to the Controller through the session

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem unless the expected field values are of different expected type. For instance a field some times carrying a float and some times carrying a string or an int. I would recommend trying to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: Try and avoid a situation where the interpreter defines the field type.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a serialized object. You can easily convert it to a json object or array using $data->toJson() or $data->toArray().